# Benefits of using Foundation's "ZURB Template" from CLI?

Tags: sass, frameworks, zurb-foundation-6, web-frontend

What are the benefits of using Foundation's ZURB Template from cli? It seems that Handlebars, TS compiling and Panini templates unnecessary, and makes the file structure very complex in a project. I spent the morning trying to wrap my head around why someone would use it vs. the basic template. What am I missing?

Comment: They are making it easy for someone who has a use-case (and the know-how) for Typescript, Handlebars, and Panini to spin up a site without having to do all the manual work of downloading, unzipping, moving, copying, configuring, etc.

Comment: Thanks Moose. That makes sense... I wanted to become a Foundation power user with the CLI and all the features but I don't think I need that much configuration-- seems very powerful for someone working in it every day, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's sole purpouse is to make it easier to develop a website. 
Actually it's only a couple of hours, and you will get it. 
It gives you the ability to make your workflow become faster and faster.
  **You should really give it a try.**